# Spell checking language in PowerPoint 2013

Tags: language, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

How do I force a change of the default spell check language in a PowerPoint document?

My windows 7 machine and office installation are all running English. However I'm using a Swedish keyboard layout.

For some reason all text boxes in PowerPoint is defaulting to Swedish which is a major pain as I manually have to go and change this every time for every text box to instead be English. This is driving me insane, surely there must be better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the Default Language option using 'Languages' from the 'Review' tab.

Go to Review tab > Language > click on the small down arrow > select Language Preferences > Language > select the "Set Language Priority order for the buttons". The screenshot is for your reference.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: This did not help me even as I removed all occurrences of "swedish" in the language settings. Possibly its hard coded into the corporate ppt templates I have installed on my machine?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean the "proofing language": Is it based on the proofing language of the template for the new presentation? Try changing the proofing language of all elements (inlcuding Master View) to your desired proofing language.